# How to randomly select and split into two teams in react hooks

Tags: reactjs, express, axios, react-hooks

I would like to randomly select players from the `array` and put into two teams. If it has got even players equally split into two teams, but if the number of players are odd (not even), then its ok to have an extra player in any team.

I have created a javascript to split into teams, but i don't get how do i push `test1`, `test2` arrays instead of  `allUsers` to two teams.

I have provided a demo link :
https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-ellis-2h3pd?file=/src/components/Team.js

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from 'axios'
import DailyStatusDialog from "../modal/DailyStatus";
import * as moment from 'moment';
    const allPlayers = [
  {
    id: "1",
    name: "Player 1",
    image: "images/photo-2345678.JPG"
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    name: "Player 2",
    image: "images/photo-2345679.JPG"
  },
  {
    id: "3",
    name: "Player 3",
    image: "images/photo-2345680.JPG"
  },
  {
    id: "4",
    name: "Player 4",
    image: "images/photo-2345681.JPG"
  },
  {
    id: "5",
    name: "Player 5",
    image: "images/photo-2345682.JPG"
  }
];

const Availability = () =>{
    const [team1, setTeam1] = useState([]);
    const [team2, setTeam2] = useState([]);
    const [deleteDialog, setDeleteDialog] = useState(false);
    const [playerId, setPlayerId] = useState("");
    const [helperText, setHelperText] = useState('');
    const loginUserEmail = localStorage.getItem('loginEmail');
    const [dailyStatusPlayers, setDailyStatusPlayers] = useState([]);
    //const [dailyinput, setDailyInput] = useState('');
    const [inCount, setInCount] = useState("");
    const isMounted = useRef(false);
    const c_day = moment().format('dddd');
    const c_date = moment().format('DD-MM-YYYY');

    let i = 0;
    const tempTeam1 = [];
    const tempTeam2 = [];
    while(allPlayers.length > 0) {
      const random = Math.floor(Math.random() * allPlayers.length);
      i%2 === 0 ? tempTeam1.push(allPlayers[random]) : tempTeam2.push(allPlayers[random]);
      allPlayers.splice(random, 1);
      i++;
    }
    setTeam1(tempTeam1);
    setTeam2(tempTeam2);
    
    useEffect(() => {
        isMounted.current = true;
        return () => isMounted.current = false;
      }, []);


    const displayAvailabilityStatus = () =>{
       setDeleteDialog(true);
    }
     
    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
          try {
            const res = await axios.get('http://localhost:8000/service/availability');
            if (isMounted.current) {
               setDailyStatusPlayers(res.data.dailyStatus);
            }
          } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
          }
        }
        fetchData();
      }, []);
    

    const onSubmit = (dailyinput) =>{
        console.log("Here Daily:"+ dailyinput);
        const dailyStatus = async () => {
            try {
                const params = {
                    email: loginUserEmail,
                };
              const res = await axios.post('http://localhost:8000/service/availability', { dailystatus: dailyinput }, {params} );
              console.log("Dailystatus update" + res.data.success);
              if (res.data.success) {
                setDeleteDialog(false);
              }
              else {
                console.log(res.data.message);
                setHelperText(res.data.message);
              }
            } catch (e) {
              setHelperText(e.response.data.message);
            }
          }
          dailyStatus();
    }

    return (
        <div className="availability_wrapper">
          <div className="displayCurrentDate">
          <b>{c_day}</b>, {c_date}
          </div>
         <h4>In: <span className="displayInCount">20</span></h4>
            <div className="wrap">
                <div className="container">
                    <div className="dailystatus_section">
                        <span className="playerdailyrecord">
                            <div className="row">
                                {
                                dailyStatusPlayers.map(({id, dailystatus}) =>(
                                <div key={id}  className="playerdailyrecord_main">
                                    <span className="dailstatus_playerphoto"><img className="dailstatus_playerImage"src="images/photo-1592866808392.JPG"></img></span>
                                <span className="dailstatus">{dailystatus}</span>
                                    <span className="dailstatus_playerposition">Forward</span>
                                </div>
                                ))        
                                }
                            </div>
                            <span className="">
                                <button className="OverlayDailyStatus" onClick={displayAvailabilityStatus}>Enter</button>
                            </span>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <div className="container">
                        <div className="playerdistribution_section">
                            <h4>Team Selection</h4>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="container">
                        <div className="weeklycount_graph_section">
                                <h4>Weekly Player Availability</h4>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <DailyStatusDialog
              onSubmit={onSubmit}
              open={deleteDialog}
              onClose={() => setDeleteDialog(false)}
            />
        </div>
    );

}
export default Availability;
```

[image]

Comment: What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it? How is this distinct from generally trying to pick from an array, how are hooks, express, axios, react involved? This seems like pure [tag:javascript].

Comment: Can you post the relevant code here in your question so no one has to go looking for it in your linked sandbox? The sandbox can change over time or be removed, so it is best to include the code here anyway. Please also include debugging and specific details about what isn't working as expected.

Comment: @DrewReese I have added the javascript code to split into teams but not sure how to push to` test1, test2` arrays instead of allusers.map and push data into two divs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a random element from the array and remove it, repeat the process until the array is empty

```js
const items = [1,2,3,4,5]
const [team1, setTeam1] = useState([]);
const [team2, setTeam2] = useState([]);

let i = 0;
const tempTeam1 = [];
const tempTeam2 = [];
while(items.length > 0) {
  const random = Math.floor(Math.random() * items.length);
  i%2 === 0 ? tempTeam1.push(items[random]) : tempTeam2.push(items[random]);
  items.splice(random, 1);
  i++;
}
setTeam1(tempTeam1);
setTeam2(tempTeam2);

<div key={name} className="left_col">
  {team1.map(name=><span>{name}</span>)}
</div>
    
<div key={name} className="right_col">
  {team2.map(name=><span>{name}</span>)}
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you mate, highly appreciated,  I have updated my question with what I have tried, could you please have look. How do i push test1 , test2 array to those divs `left_col` and `right_col`

Comment: You will need to use state variables

Comment: I will try that and reply back, awesome help for a new starter person  like me in reactjs

Comment: I am getting two errors  like error occurred in the <Availability> component:
    in Availability (at protected.route.js:10)
    in Route (at protected.route.js:6)
    in ProtectedRoute (at App.js:38)
    in Switch (at App.js:34)
    in UserProfileProvider (at App.js:31)
    in UserLoginProvider (at App.js:30)
    in Router (created by BrowserRouter)
    in BrowserRouter (at App.js:29)
    in App
 Uncaught Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:14815)

Comment: When i add this I am getting too many renders error....`const [team1, setTeam1] = useState([]);
    const [team2, setTeam2] = useState([]);

    let i = 0;
    const tempTeam1 = [];
    const tempTeam2 = [];
    while(allPlayers.length > 0) {
      const random = Math.floor(Math.random() * allPlayers.length);
      i%2 === 0 ? tempTeam1.push(allPlayers[random]) : tempTeam2.push(allPlayers[random]);
      allPlayers.splice(random, 1);
      i++;
    }
    setTeam1(tempTeam1);
    setTeam2(tempTeam2);`

Comment: You need to put the useState consts  outside the function, at the beginning of the file

Comment: I have added to the question how  does it look like...

Comment: All good, it is working now, I have added `  useEffect(() => {
    setTeam1(tempTeam1);
    setTeam2(tempTeam2);
    },[]);`